# Efficient way to count future dates by group

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a data.table where I need to count the number of future start dates that appear after the current date. The number of start dates needs to be split up by ID instead of unique starts dates.

Here is an example of the data.table.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
test = data.table(ID = rep("A", 10), ID_2 = c(rep("B", 5), rep("C", 2), rep("D", 2), "E"), Date = c(as.Date("2014-01-01") + months(0:4),as.Date("2014-04-01") + months(0:1), as.Date("2014-04-01") + months(0:1), as.Date("2014-05-01")), ID_2_start = c(rep(as.Date("2014-01-01"),5), rep(as.Date("2014-04-01"),2), rep(as.Date("2014-04-01"),2), as.Date("2014-05-01")), ID_2_end = c(rep(as.Date("2014-02-01"),5), rep(as.Date("2014-10-01"),5)))
> test
    ID ID_2       Date ID_2_start   ID_2_end
 1:  A    B 2014-01-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
 2:  A    B 2014-02-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
 3:  A    B 2014-03-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
 4:  A    B 2014-04-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
 5:  A    B 2014-05-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01
 6:  A    C 2014-04-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01
 7:  A    C 2014-05-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01
 8:  A    D 2014-04-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01
 9:  A    D 2014-05-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01
10:  A    E 2014-05-01 2014-05-01 2014-10-01
```

The future start dates needs to be the length of unique ID_2 that have a start date after the current date.

The expected output is this.

```
    ID ID_2       Date ID_2_start   ID_2_end future_start
 1:  A    B 2014-01-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01            3
 2:  A    B 2014-02-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01            3
 3:  A    B 2014-03-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01            3
 4:  A    B 2014-04-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01            1
 5:  A    B 2014-05-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01            0
 6:  A    C 2014-04-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01            1
 7:  A    C 2014-05-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01            0
 8:  A    D 2014-04-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01            1
 9:  A    D 2014-05-01 2014-04-01 2014-10-01            0
10:  A    E 2014-05-01 2014-05-01 2014-10-01            0
```

The only way I could come up with to do this is create a function where I pass the Date, ID_2, and ID_2_start. Then, I can create a list of unique ID_2_start by ID and sum the number of ID_2_start that is greater than the current date with sapply.

```
fut_start = function(date, start_dates, id_2){
  tmp = unique(data.table(id_2, start_dates))

  tmp2 = sapply(date, function(x) sum(x < tmp$start_dates))

  return(tmp2)
}

test[ , "future_start" := fut_start(date = Date, start_dates = ID_2_start, id_2 = ID_2), by = .(ID)]
```

This does give the expected output, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: Please include library(...) calls. There is no such thing as months(0:1) with data.table.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I have them in there now.

Comment: I think this should do `test[test, on = .(ID, ID_2_start > Date), uniqueN(ID_2, na.rm = TRUE), by = .EACHI]$V1`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the response. This gives the same result as above and is much faster. I'm not totally sure I understand how it is counting the unique values though. I haven't used data.table merge much, but from what I've been reading it looks like it joins as long by ID as long as ID_2_start > date, which makes sense. What i don't understand though is if you print out `test[test, on = .(ID, ID_2_start > Date), allow.cartesian = TRUE]` not all of the Dates are there. And, I thought .EACHI would refer to the values in on, but if that's true I don't see how uniqueN returns the rightval

Comment: @DavidArenburg nm, I think I get it. Printing it out still looks weird to me but the logic for final counts makes sense. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The root problem is malformed data. Create `DT2 = unique(test[, .(ID = ID_2, start = ID_2_start, end = ID_2_end)])` and delete those columns from test. Then the analogous code to what David wrote will be clearer and more efficient, I guess. `DT2[test, on=.(start > Date), .N, by=.EACHI]$N`. Also, it'll be a lot faster with IDates rather than Dates, judging by my experience.